# Как автоматически определить категорию слова

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, автоматизация

Есть список слов (количество от 1000 - до 3000) и есть 30 категорий. Можно ли автоматически как-то определить подходящую категорию для каждого слова по смыслу (по семантике)?

Например: 
слова = мама, папа, брат, хлеб, пирог, мясо, молоко....
категории = семья, еда,....

Результат:
семья = мама, папа, брат
еда = хлеб, пирог, мясо, молоко

Comment: Можно, ключевое слово онтологии

Comment: В каком виде ваш список слов, есть ли какие-то смысловые семантические подсказки, или это просто массив через запятую?

Comment: Скорее просто массив. Расчет на то, что есть уже готовая библиотека, которая выдает предпологаемые категории для слова, и если какая-либо из выданных категорий находится в списке, то соответственно этому слову и присваевается эта категория. Надеюсь, что доступно объяснил

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/277413/ для начала

Answer (score 2):

Можно спарсить какой-нибудь сайт или несколько, где слова уже разбиты по категориям.

Например: http://rus.lang-study.com/category/slovar/

При желании можно также [лемматизировать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) слова, чтобы научиться категоризировать существительные в любой форме.

Answer (score 1):

Для компьютера слова это просто слова, сам по себе он не может определять смысл слова, или лексическую или логическую группу.

Конечно это можно сделать вручную. Создать список групп, в каждую группы внести слова этой группы, и уже на основе этих групп, если на вход подаётся слово, и слово входит в одну из групп, на выход выдавать эту группу.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать такой алгоритм.

Берём каждую группу и слово обозначающее группу. Ищем в яндексе это слово и берём скажем первые 40 текстов. Проходимся по каждому тексту и смотрим сколько раз какое слово из списка 3000 входит в даннный текст. Таким образом составляем таблицу

[имя группы]
слово1 входит 0 раз
слово2 входит 3 раз
слово3 входит 15 раз
слово4 входит 0 раза

Далее проходимся по всем словам из 3000 и смотрим в какую группу оно входит с наибольшем значением, в эту группу и определяем слово.
Алгоритм конечно простой, при желании можно его совершенствовать.

Comment: Идея рабочая, но затратная по времени и ресурсам (на первый взгляд). Как уже комментировал раньше,  расчет на то, что есть уже готовая библиотека, которая выдает предпологаемые категории для слова. Это бы во много раз упростило бы задачу. Возможно уже есть готовое решение от Google или Yandex, в поиске которого я и нахожусь

Comment: @Anton кстати всё-таки достаточно быстро можно сделать такой алгоритм, всё-же он очень простой. С другой стороны если вы найдёте уже готовое решение то конечно это может быть лучше. Но ещё с другой стороны не факт что вам это готовое решение подойдёт, а если и подойдёт то сколько потребуется времени на адаптацию.

Answer (score 0):

такой примитивный вариант для вашего конкретнего примера

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

enum Category {family, food };
void print_result(Category N, const std::multimap<Category, std::string>& g) {
    auto P = g.equal_range(N);
    while(P.first != P.second) {
        std::cout << P.first->second << ", ";
        ++P.first;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::multimap<Category, std::string> group{
        {family, "mama"}, {family, "dad"}, {family, "brother"},
        {food, "bread"}, {food, "tart"}, {food, "meat"}, {food, "milk"}
    };
    std::cout << "family" << " = ";
    print_result(family, group);
    std::cout << "food" << "   = ";
    print_result(food, group);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В вашем коде категории уже заранее определены для каждого из слов. Задача стоит такая, чтобы , зная только слова, определить подходящую категорию из другого списка

Comment: НУ введите в multimap из другого списка, в любом варианте вы сами должны указывать что есть что. Потом я же  отметил, что это примитивный пример для наглядности - конечно можно все проделать с помощью классов и получать данные из  списка и потока, постепенно добавляя в список категорий новые термины.... можете следовать совету MaxU - я лишь написал наглядный пример

Comment: почти каждую задачу можно решать многими вариантами,  также как эту.  Но вы сами должны выбирать вариант решения, поскольку  именно вам известно  для чего вы это делаете,  и  по мере своих знаний выбирать вариант и путь решения.  Примеры  - это просто пища